# Suppose $c_{n,d}$ is the number of integers $m$ such that $1\leq m \leq n$ and $gcd(n,m)=d$. Explain why $n=\sum_{1\leq d\leq n} c_{n,d}$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, divisibility

Suppose $c_{n,d}$ is the number of integers $m$ such that $1\leq m \leq n$ and $gcd(n,m)=d$. Explain why $n=\sum_{1\leq d\leq n} c_{n,d}$. I don't have much intuition on why this fact is true. This fact was used to prove that $n=\sum_{d|n}\phi(d)$ where $\phi(d)$ is the Euler function but I wasn't quite sure why the fact was true. I understood everything else about the proof. I was wondering if someone could explain.

Comment: Each $m\le n$ is in one and only one $c_{n,d}$.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most helpful way to go about proving this fact would be noting the following: For all $n\geq 1$, letting $[1,n]$ denote the interval of integers between $1$ and $n$ there is a decomposition into the disjoint union

$$[1,n]=\bigcup_{d=1}^{n}\left\{m\in [1,n]\,\,\mathrm{such \,\,that}\,\, \gcd(n,m)=d\right\}.$$

This is true because every $m$ has $\gcd(n,m)=d$ for some unique value $d$. Thus, looking at the size of the sets on each side we have that

\begin{align*}
n&=\mathrm{size}([1,n])\\
&=\mathrm{size}\left(\bigcup_{d=1}^{n}\left\{m\in [1,n]\,\,\mathrm{such \,\,that}\,\, \gcd(n,m)=d\right\}\right)\\
&=\sum_{d=1}^{n}\mathrm{size}\left(\left\{m\in [1,n]\,\,\mathrm{such \,\,that}\,\, \gcd(n,m)=d\right\}\right)\\
&=\sum_{d=1}^{n}c_{n,d}.
\end{align*}

Looking at the start and end of this chain of equalities we get the result!